# Hibernate Junit hsqldb - (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

My Dao layer works fine with the MySql. When I try to unit test the same with the in memory db (HSQLDB) I am not able to persist data. My entity is defined as follows

```
public class Api {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "api_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int apiId;
```

When trying to persist the id is not auto generated. It is passed as null.

```
18:05:52.071 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into api (api_id, description, version) values (null, ?, ?)
18:05:52.076 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not prepare statement [insert into api (api_id, description, name) values (null, ?, ?)]
```

My hibernate properties are

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ApiConstants.HIBERNATE_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    properties.setProperty(ApiConstants.HIBERNATE_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    properties.setProperty(ApiConstants.HIBERNATE_CONN_URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:apicloud");
    properties.setProperty(ApiConstants.HIBERNATE_CONN_USER, "sa");
    properties.setProperty(ApiConstants.HIBERNATE_CONN_PWD, "");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class,hbm");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
```

Schema is created every time the unit test is triggered. Create statement is issued as follows.

```
18:05:51.995 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table api 
(api_id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
description varchar(255), version varchar(255), primary key (api_id))
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Your code should work correctly. Which versions of HSQLDB and Hibernate are you using? Also, can you enable DEBUG logging for org.hibernate and look for the "CREATE TABLE" statement for the Api model? You should see that the column is created with "identity" - if not, that is your problem.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the response.. My hibernate version is 4.3.6.Final and HSQLDB version is 2.2.8. I have added the create table statement as well in the above question and I could see the table is generated with the identity.. Still the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved when I updated the HSQLDB version to 2.2.9.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043498&p=2490106#p2490106

Pradeep.